# Android: How to detect parent tag of XML tags

Tags: android, xml, parsing, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to get values in under specific xml tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026916/android-how-to-get-values-in-under-specific-xml-tags)

Hi guys, I want to detect the parent tags of my XML file to download and rename the correct file. I have [my code on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026916/android-how-to-get-values-in-under-specific-xml-tags/6027016).

Comment: See my suggestion to use Simple XML instead on your other post.

Comment: I think your answer to my other post wasn't saved? It's not there...

Comment: I got an answer to this question [in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026916/android-how-to-get-values-in-under-specific-xml-tags/6027016).

Comment: Just look at this blog post. It explains how to use Simple XML in Android: https://massaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can select any node in your XML document, you can then use XPath's `ancestor`  axis to find all ancestors (see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp). Then test them, and if one doesn't have its own ancestor then it's your root element.