# How to store the data string into an array

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-maps

I have a problem which has left me confused.

This is the problem.

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Turn left onto Jalan Raden Ajeng Kartini</name>
<description><![CDATA[go 550&#160;m]]></description>
<StyleMap>
<Pair>
    <key>normal</key>
    <Style>
        <IconStyle>
        <Icon><href>http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/kml/paddle/pause.png</href></Icon>
        <hotSpot x="0.500000" y="0.000000" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
        </IconStyle>
        <ListStyle>
        <ItemIcon><href>http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/kml/paddle/pause-lv.png</href></ItemIcon>
        </ListStyle>
    </Style>
</Pair>
<Pair>
    <key>highlight</key>
    <Style>
        <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.300000</scale>
        <Icon><href>http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/kml/paddle/pause.png</href></Icon>
        <hotSpot x="0.500000" y="0.000000" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
        </IconStyle>
        <ListStyle>
        <ItemIcon><href>http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/kml/paddle/pause-lv.png</href></ItemIcon>
        </ListStyle>
    </Style>
</Pair>
</StyleMap>
<Point>
    <coordinates>106.827140,-6.296370,0</coordinates>
</Point>
<LookAt>
    <longitude>106.827140</longitude>
    <latitude>-6.296370</latitude>
    <range>100.000000</range>
    <tilt>45.000000</tilt>
    <heading>347.976074</heading>
</LookAt>
</Placemark>
```

In the tag *Placemark* we can see child tag `<name>...</name>` which contains String value like "*Turn left onto jalan Raden Ajeng Kartini*"

In my XML document I found many tag names such as this one. How do I save them to an Array?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026916/android-how-to-get-values-in-under-specific-xml-tags)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking. But i think you need an XML parser for android.

I recommend reading the guide on this link: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example